# Use of | symbol in Powershell scripting command

Tags: powershell

Looking at the following code:

```
$securePassword = $password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
```

What does the `|` symbol do and what role does it play in the command?

Answer (score 4):

The <kbd>|</kbd>, or pipe as it is more commonly known, is basically an operator that takes the output from the expression on the left and "pipes" or passes it along as input to the expression on the right side of the pipe character.

In the case of your example, it takes the value in the `$password` variable and passes it as input to the ConvertTo-SecureString cmdlet which captures the plain text password and protects it inside a secured string. You could write the above command identically just without the pipe as:

```
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
```

There is a decent, though older explanation on TechNet that gets into more depth about piping and what it means for PowerShell: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176927.aspx

Answer (score 2):

`|` is the pipe operator. It 'pipes' the output from $password, which is likely to be a string. At the other end of the pipe is a command `ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force`. By the name, this command converts the plaintext *piped* from the $password variable to a `securestring`. This all gets put into the `$securePassword` variable by the `=`.

Pipes enable the programmer to chain commands together.

Answer (score 1):

It's the piping command. You use it to send the output of one command to another.

For example: `Get-ChildItems -filter ".cs" | Select-string -pattern "Hello World"`

This set of commands searches for all the .cs files in a directory, and then looks for "Hello World" in each of those files.

[Piping Explanation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176927.aspx)